# How is the super method to be used in Django?

Tags: python, django, super

I don't want you to think I would be lazy. I already read about the super method to override pre-existing methods in Django (and possibly also in Python in general). Still I must admit that I did not really understand everything.

So, instead of asking for a particular application of the method, I wanted to ask how this method can be applied. Sounds weird or too broad? Perhaps it helps, if I describe my problem.

Let's say I want to enhance a class-based view. My experience with them is also limited. Very often, pages on the web just say, "yeah, you have to override this or that method."
Me, "Ehm, how do I actually know about the existence of this or that method?" So far, I have to come to know a few like get, post and form_valid, but I do not know in general which are available or where I have to read them up, as I guess that they are in subclasses of subclasses of subclasses in some general files and I don't even know where those are.

So, imagine I have found the corresponding method, then I do not know how to handle that.
Here is an example. I wanted to customize an update view so that it also works if I call it from a button within a post method form.

```
class Update_Org(UpdateView):
    model = OrgKlass
    form_class = form_update_org
    template_name = templ_folder_name + 'update_org.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy(url_app_name + 'list_org')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        self.queryset = OrgKlass.objects.get(id = self.to_update)
        return self.queryset

    def post(self, request, pk):
        if self.request.POST.get('action', False) == 'update':
            self.to_update = pk
            self.object = self.get_object()
            return super(Update_Org, self).post(request, pk)
        else:
            [...]
```

I thought that this would override the post method, that I would retrieve the corresponding object with self.get_object() (which seems to work) and that this would prepopulate the form, but it does not.
How can I learn to find the right way to do such things?

Sorry, if my question is still too broad.

Comment: Either the documentation would very explicitly describe how to override the method exactly, or you would need to read the source code of the parent method. For example, if `UpdateView.post` itself did a `self.object = ...`, then whatever you do in `Update_Org.post` would simply be overwritten. How to work nicely with parent methods really depends on the details of what the parent method does. Usually you'll want to read its code. A good IDE helps a lot here to locate that code quickly.

Comment: what do you mean by "prepopulate the form"? intention of POST is to update the DB with incoming values from request. Is that what you meant?

Comment: **Ehm, how do I actually know about the existence of this or that method?**
Other than looking up online, use ```dir``` function ```dir(UpdateView)```

Comment: Thanks!
@drd: I have another view in which I have a form. In this form there are several buttons. One of them is an "Update" button. I am really no expert, but I heard so often that it would be better to use post method instead of get. But I already found that the form of the corresponding model is only filled with the pre-existing data if the UpdateView is called via get method and not via post method. Therefore, in this particular setting, I want to override post so that the existing data is being filled in in the form.

Comment: I would just like to understand how to use super for my tasks and not to always ask for help for a particular setting. :(
Just wanted to add this, so that you understand why my question was so broad.

Comment: The `post` method is for handling the form *submission*. Presenting the form is handled by the `get` method. You need to override *that* for populating the form.

Comment: But even then I would need to understand how that works.

Comment: *how do I actually know about the existence of this or that method* - that's a disadvantage of using class based views in Django. You can use [`ccbv`](https://ccbv.co.uk/) to explore which methods are available.

Comment: I am it. Thanks!

Comment: Furthermore: Anyone with an idea how to solve this post problem above?

Comment: And about the super method. If I understand it right, the super method does not overwrite everything from the old method, right?
If I have something like

class ABC 
    def xyz (request, *args, **kwargs):
         self.something = somethingelse
         return super(ABC, self).xyz(request, *args, **kwargs)

Does this mean that xyz is only changed with regard to self.something? Will the rest of the original xyz still be used? Do I always have to call super upon the class in which the def is and always with self as a second argument?